# python read a file, save a new column for each line ad save the same file

Tags: python, performance, save, overwrite

I have a file with x,y,z values. I wish to find an elegant way to open and add a new value id to each line and save again the same file.

```
def get_point_grid_id(x,y,x_min,y_max,x_dist,y_dist):
    col = int((x - x_min)/x_dist)
    row = int((y_max - y)/y_dist)
    return (row, col)
```

ex

```
1 1 10
2 2 10
3 3 10
```

the id will be

```
get_point_grid_id(1,1,0,10,1,1)
(9, 1)
get_point_grid_id(2,2,0,10,1,1)
(8, 2)
get_point_grid_id(3,3,0,10,1,1)
(7, 3)
```

the new file will be

```
1 1 10 (9, 1)
2 2 10 (8, 2)
3 3 10 (7, 3)
```

i am reading in Stackoverflow several approach and i tested several approaches. i am honest to say  that i have tried and failed to save the new file.

i had tried the followig solution

```
with open(file_temp, "r+") as f:
    for line in open(file_temp):
        x,y,z = line.split()
        id = get_point_grid_id(float(x),float(y),0,10,1,1)
        element = [x,y,z,id]
        newelement = " ".join([str(e) for e in element])+ "\n"
        f.write(newelement)
```

but i get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

where newelement (real data) is

```
'481499.55 6244324.75 19.15 (377, 2909)\n'
```

Comment: Write to a separate file and then rename back!

Comment: yes was a solution but the file is already huge (more than 10 GB)

Comment: Dear @SudiptaChatterjee thanks, but i am looking for a save coding solution. I am sure there is a way to open and replace line by line in python

Comment: Due to sequential nature of today's storage devices, inserting a byte in a middle of a file implies that the remaining data will need to be moved over by one byte. I am not sure there is any filesystem today that supports this. The best three alternatives I can come up with are: (1) create a new file with the updated data and rename it at the end, (2) save the data in a database such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and let the database library take care of updating fields, (3) save the data in a structured format that supports in-place updates to dataset (HDF5 might work for this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate the required behavior via the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module but bear in mind that it will create a backup copy of your original 10GB+ file in the background:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

def get_point_grid_id(x,y,x_min,y_max,x_dist,y_dist):
    col = int((x - x_min)/x_dist)
    row = int((y_max - y)/y_dist)
    return (row, col)

input_file = "test.dat"
#
# Add mode='rb' to the arguments of fileinput.input() if you are
# using a binary file on operating systems that differentiate 
# between binary and text files (e.g. Microsoft Windows). 
#
for line in fileinput.input(input_file, inplace=True):
    columns = line.split()
    if 3 == len(columns):
        x, y, z = columns
        id = get_point_grid_id(float(x),float(y),0,10,1,1)
        print "{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(x, y, z, id)
```

The `inplace` parameter passed to `fileinput.input` triggers the magic.

Comment: Using something with `fileinput.input(...inplace=True)` is the way I would approach it +1

Comment: dear @crayzeewulf and Jon thanks for support. I am working with an other solution (line-by-line) but i get an error message (see above the update)

Comment: @Gianni, I think you might have more than three entries on a line somewhere in the input file. The error message (`ValueError: too many values to unpack`) is probably on the line: `x,y,z = line.split()`. I have updated my sample code above to process only the lines that have exactly three columns. This may not be ideal for you but you can easily modify the `if` statement to suite your needs.

Comment: dear @crayzeewulf thanks for the suppor. I moved the question on this new page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033309/python-help-to-debug-an-error-when-modify-a-file-in-a-stream-mode/15033470#15033470

Comment: :) I also just realized that you are writing the updated data to the same file object (`f`). This is not going to do what you think it should do (as pointed out by several comments at the new page). I think you are expecting it to update the current line and leave the rest of the file untouched but in reality it will overwrite portions of the data in the file. You ought to try using the code I listed above.

Comment: dear @crayzeewulf i didn't get the command "print" to save the newelement :P sorry

Comment: Gianni, you are probably not alone. The fact that the `print` statement actually writes to `input_file` is not obvious but that is the correct behavior according to the documentation.

Comment: @crayzeewulfi have this problem using your solution. The new file repets the line  two times. One times without id and one time yes
481498.79 6244494.44 29.72 <br/> 481498.79 6244494.44 29.72 (41, 581) <br/> 481498.77 6244494.61 30.13 <br/> 481498.77 6244494.61 30.13 (41, 581) <br/> 481498.75 6244494.79 30.50 <br/> 481498.75 6244494.79 30.5 (41, 581) <br/> 481498.77 6244494.85 30.06
481498.77 6244494.85 30.06 (41, 581) <br/> 481498.91 6244495.22 27.61 <br/> 481498.91 6244495.22 27.61 (41, 581) <br/>

Comment: Gianni, I do not see this behavior. Do you mind putting your actual complete code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so I can have a look at it.

Comment: @crayzeewulf i fixed this behavior using fileinput.input(input_file, inplace=True, mode="rb"): in this case i have only line 1 1 10 (9, 1). Furthermore, with "sys.stdout.write(newelement)" you can save instead of "print"

Comment: Thanks for the update, Gianni. I have added a comment in my answer to warn users that "mode='rb'" might be needed in some cases. I am using Linux so the 'b' option has no affect for me. But it might be needed on Microsoft Windows, for example.