# Python help to debug an error when modify a file in a stream mode

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, streamwriter

I have the following problem. I am reading a file x,y,z as:

```
481492.93 6244326.24 26.56
481493.03 6244325.60 25.06
481493.17 6244324.68 22.89
481493.50 6244322.52 17.80
481492.84 6244327.05 27.84
481492.90 6244326.66 26.90
481492.86 6244327.16 27.45
481493.48 6244323.08 17.79
481492.80 6244327.80 28.30
481492.94 6244326.84 26.04
..........................
```

i wish to read, modify, and write on the same file (without create a back-up file because the originals file is more than 10GB)

```
481492.93 6244326.24 26.56 (375, 2902)
481493.03 6244325.60 25.06 (376, 2902)
481493.17 6244324.68 22.89 (377, 2902)
481493.50 6244322.52 17.80 (379, 2903)
481492.84 6244327.05 27.84 (375, 2902)
481492.90 6244326.66 26.90 (375, 2902)
481492.86 6244327.16 27.45 (374, 2902)
481493.48 6244323.08 17.79 (379, 2903)
481492.80 6244327.80 28.30 (374, 2902)
481492.94 6244326.84 26.04 (375, 2902)
..........................
```

i wrote the following approach

```
def get_point_grid_id(x,y,x_min,y_max,x_dist,y_dist):
        col = int((x - x_min)/x_dist)
        row = int((y_max - y)/y_dist)
        return (row, col)

with open(file_temp, "r+") as f:
    for line in open(file_temp):
        x,y,z = line.split()
        id = get_point_grid_id(float(x),float(y),origin[0],origin[1],1,1)
        element = [x,y,z,id]
        newelement = " ".join([str(e) for e in element])+ "\n"
        f.write(newelement)
```

when i run the function i got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

i suppose it's a connection problem with the original file

the error appears

```
>>> x,y,z = line.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

where `line` is strange

```
'481499.82 6244470.31 29.23 (231, 2909)\n'
```

instead of  `'481499.82 6244470.31 29.23\n'`

using `print line` after `for line in open(file_temp):` i got this print after run from a new file

```
481499.98 6244494.02 34.14
481499.98 6244494.02 34.14 (208, 2909)
481499.96 6244471.05 33.39
481499.96 6244471.05 33.39 (231, 2909)
481499.95 6244471.27 33.46
481499.95 6244471.27 33.46 (230, 2909)
481499.98 6244473.84 32.72
481499.98 6244473.84 32.72 (228, 2909)
481499.98 6244474.07 32.70
481499.98 6244474.07 32.70 (228, 2909)
481499.97 6244474.28 32.93
481499.97 6244474.28 32.93 (227, 2909)
481499.88 6244474.40 34.35
481499.88 6244474.40 34.35 (227, 2909)
```

Comment: Try doing `print line` before doing `x,y,z=line.split()`. It looks like you *might* be overwriting portions of your file.

Comment: This is not going to work (reading and writing at the same time) because the lines that you are writing out are *longer* than the lines you are reading in. That is physically just not going to fit; you'll be overtaking your read operations with overwritten data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and Joel, thanks for help I update my question using print line before doing x,y,z=line.split()

Comment: `with open(file_temp, "r+") as f:` assigns a reference to your file object to f.  `For line in f:` should follow instead of opening the file again.

Comment: Thanks all for support. I cannot figure out i fixed this problem. Probably I need to write from "0" the approach. It's the first time I am doing this type of operation

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you suggest to create a back-up file and delete the original?

Comment: @Gianni: You'll have to.

Comment: @EricRoper: The OP is trying to both read and write to the same file, which is probably why it was opened twice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks you are always great and professional. Nowi need to understand i do that :D

Comment: @Gianni: Take a look at the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html); the `inplace` flag implements what you need I think.

Comment: Related question from OP with more information: [python read a file, save a new column for each line ad save the same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030038/python-read-a-file-save-a-new-column-for-each-line-ad-save-the-same-file/15031090#comment21127653_15031090)

Comment: I think this actually works.  I have a simple example that works.  I will craft it to the required format.

Comment: dear @MartijnPieters and crayzeewulf, thanks fileinput module is a exotic module for me, but we always need to learn new techniques

Comment: @EricRoper: I'd love to see you try; the input lines are *shorter* than what is being written out, so each new line requires more space than what was there. You'll have to read the whole file into memory before you can rewrite the file, and with a 10GB inputfile that's just not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

opening the line in r+ mode means that you read a line, ie 38 characters read.
Then you modify those 38 characters
Then, at the current file position (character 39) you over write the existing data

I would guess this is not what you want

Hope this helps

Comment: dear @Vorsprung i wish to replace (or update) the line add the "id"value

Comment: Gianni, I don't see a way of doing it without creating a new file- which you wish to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

This just isn't going to work. As Martijn said,

### I

`file` objects have a buffer position. Every time you read a character the buffer position advances by 1. Suppose you read a line that's 10 characters long:

```
>>> myfile = open('some_file.txt')
>>> myfile.tell() #gets the buffer position
0
>>> myfile.readline()
'012345678\n'
```

Now the buffer position is advanced by `len(line)` characters:

```
>>> myfile.tell()
10
```

This means that when you call `myfile.write()`, it starts writing at position 10.

### II

You simply can't "insert" characters into a file without overwriting something, or appending characters to the end (assuming that the buffer position is at the end of the file).

### So what do you do?

You can create a temporary file, and simultaneously read from your input file, and write to your temp file. Afterwards (if you should wish), you can replace your original file with the temporary one:

```
with open(input_file) as infile, open(output_temp_file, "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        x, y, z = line.split()
        new_line = ' '.join([x, y, z] + [function_of_xyz(x, y, z)]) + '\n'
        outfile.write(new_line)
```

You should also check out the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).